# How can I output diff'ed text into a separate file? python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, compare, diff

so I'm trying to make a bot that sends a message after comparing two text files (which are generated using `requests.get('url=').text` method) displaying only new lines/text/whichever that has been added/removed.

I know there is difflib. `HtmlDiff(make_file())` doesn't suit me because it just makes a mess in a file. Plus it's only needed to output an html file anyway, from what I understand. You then open it in the browser and Wuala! You have the comparisons.

I tried searching, but can't find such a library that outputs only the text that has been changed/added.

Currently I did this:

```
def htmlCompare(prep_id=None):
while True:
    prep_url = requests.get(prep_template.format(prep_id))
    c1 = prep_url
    c2 = ''
    if c2 != c1:
        compare = difflib.HtmlDiff().make_file(fromlines=c1, tolines=c2, numlines=1)
        c2 = c1
        config_compare_save = open('compare_{}_main.txt'.format(prep_id), 'w')
        config_compare_save.write(compare)
        config_compare_save.close()
    else:  # don't mind this meaningless condition for now, I left this for something for later :)
        time.sleep(10)
```

but this just doesn't give me the result I need, as you can tell. Tried to use `Differ()`, but it looks like I don't know how to use it. Not even sure if that's the method I need to use in the first place. But from what I can tell, this is the closest to what I might have to use.

Comment: @stovfl, completely irrelevant... I don't need to highlight anything, I need to output the diff itself, without any other info, in a separate text file.

Comment: @stovfl so like, trying to figure out how exactly it highlights in the HtmlDiff method, and use the same, but with having the highlighted text be exported? If that, then I could try, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Tried to use Differ(), ... from what I can tell, this is the closest to what I might have to use.

**Note**: Only the **first** line of `..._data` are **equal**!

```
import difflib

_old_data = "refno,title,author,year,price\n\
1001,CPP,MILTON,2008,456\n\
1002,JAVA,Gilson,2002,456\n\
1003,Adobe Flex,,2010,566\n\
1004,General Knowledge,Sinson,2007,465\n\
1005,Actionscript,Gilto,2008,480\n".splitlines(keepends=False)

_new_data = "refno,title,author,year,price\n\
1001,CPP,MILTON,2010,456,2008\n\
1002,JAVA,Gilson,2002\n\
1003,Adobe Flexi,Johnson,2010,566\n\
1004,General Knowledge,Simpson,2007,465\n\
105,Action script,Gilto,2008,480\n\
2000,Drama,DayoNe,,2020,560\n".splitlines(keepends=False)

diff = difflib.Differ()

for line in diff.compare(_old_data, _new_data):
    if line.startswith(('?',' ')):
        # Skip diff control lines ?
        # Skip equal lines ' '
        pass
    else:
        #print(line[2:])
        print(line)
```

> **Qutput**:
>   - 1001,CPP,MILTON,2008,456
>   + 1001,CPP,MILTON,2010,456,2008
>   - 1002,JAVA,Gilson,2002,456
>   + 1002,JAVA,Gilson,2002
>   - 1003,Adobe Flex,,2010,566
>   + 1003,Adobe Flexi,Johnson,2010,566
>   - 1004,General Knowledge,Sinson,2007,465
>   + 1004,General Knowledge,Simpson,2007,465
>   - 1005,Actionscript,Gilto,2008,480
>   + 105,Action script,Gilto,2008,480
>   + 2000,Drama,DayoNe,,2020,560

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it. Looks good enough, thanks!
I'll use that.